# What is the recommended path to save auto - generated files in?

Tags: windows, winforms, file, save, default

I am currently building a WinForms app and I need to create a `bin` file
in which I will serialize data. I let the user choose in which folder he wants the file to be saved in, but if he doesn't choose anything I want to save the file in a default path.

The thing is, I am not so familiar with windows' file system, and I am unable to find a good folder to save the file in.

My requirements from such folder are:

- All windows computers should have it
- The path to this folder all windows computer is the same
- Is used for programs' auto-generated files as an "international  default"
- Not used frequently by the user (a "just don't touch" folder)

what is the common solution for such things?

Answer (score 0):

You cas use a dedicated common ProgramData folder:

```
string CommonAppDataFolderPath 
  = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
  + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
  + AssemblyCompany
  + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
  + AssemblyTitle
  + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;

public string AssemblyCompany
{
  get
  {
    object[] attributes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyCompanyAttribute), false);
    if ( attributes.Length == 0 )
    {
      return "";
    }
    return ((AssemblyCompanyAttribute)attributes[0]).Company;
  }
}

public string AssemblyTitle
{
  get
  {
    object[] attributes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyTitleAttribute), false);
    if ( attributes.Length > 0 )
    {
      AssemblyTitleAttribute titleAttribute = (AssemblyTitleAttribute)attributes[0];
      if ( titleAttribute.Title != "" )
      {
        return titleAttribute.Title;
      }
    }
    return System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is AppData and you can get it with Environment.GetFolderPath:
(Environment is in System.IO namespace)

```
string binPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "SomeAppName");
// this will return something like this:
// C:\Users\SomeUserName\AppData\Roaming\SomeAppName
```

Comment: Is ```C:\Users\SomeUserName\AppData\Roaming\SomeAppName``` exist or should I create it?

Comment: And what ```"SomeAppName"``` stands for? Is it *my* app name?

Comment: Is the program going to be used by multiple users on the same PC? There is a folder(normally hidden) called programdata. This folders is used to stored application data rather than user data, so depending on how you intend to use the app this might be suitable. Have a look here: - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: You should create it, and yes, SomeAppName is your app name.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `System.Reflection` to identify a path in the debug or release folder of your assembly:

```
public static string Path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase), "someapp");
```